# download links from a web page with renaming

Tags: html, linux, rename, wget

I'm trying to find a way to automatically download all links from a web page, but I also want to rename them. for example:

```
<a href = fileName.txt> Name I want to have </a>
```

I want to be able to get a file named 'Name I want to have' (I don't worry about the extension).

I am aware that I could get the page source, then parse all the links, and download them all manually, but I'm wondering if there are any built-in tools for that.

```
lynx --dump | grep http:// | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

will print all the links that can be batch fetched with wget - but is there a way to rename the links on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by converting the web page entirely to unicode on the first pass (using notepad++'s built-in conversion)

Then I wrote a small shell script that used cat, awk and wget to fetch all the data.

Unfortunately, I couldn't automate the process since I didn't find any tools for linux which would convert an entire page from KOI8-R to unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anything does this out of the box.  I suggest you write a script in Python or similar to download the page, and load the source (try the Beautiful Soup library for tolerant parsing).  Then it's a simple matter of traversing the source to capture the links with their attributes and text, and download the files with the names you want.  With the exception of Beautiful Soup (if you need to be able to parse sloppy HTML), all you need is built in with Python.

Comment: thanks for the advice what language/framework to use. Another problem is that the entire page is in a non-unicode encoding (KOI8-R) do you know if Beatuful Soup has any support for various encodings?

Comment: If you look at the first couple paragraphs on its homepage, it says it tries to autodetect, and if that fails you can specify a source encoding, and it converts to UTF-8.